# Change color to a link that is opened in an other frame

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS programming. I have a web page that is split in two frames, one has a menu with links and the other one shows the page corresponding to the link clicked in the menu frame.

Is it possible to change the color of the link text in the menu frame according to the page showed in the other frame / last clicked link?

Comment: When you say frame..do you mean divs(element blocks etc) or iframes?

Comment: @BrS With frames i mean `<frameset>` and `<frame>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use javascript on iframe content.

and to change its element css you need to use js the catch the element.

the browsers prevent functionality like this to prevent phishings.

Comment: So it can probably be done through the server, but this is no beginners task.

Comment: yes you might do something like this. if you got your answer pls mark me as the correct answer

Comment: I am not the guy how asked the question.. you just beat me to the answer so I had to give you my 2 cents :)

Comment: I'm not using iframes but frames, does it work in the same way for both?
How can it can be done through the server?